# getElementsByTagName not returning any tags ( .length function returning 0)

Tags: excel, vba, getelementsbytagname

I am trying to extract a value from a webpage containing XML using VBA and IE automation. Currently, this program opens an IE browser, copies XML code into a window and clicks a button resulting in calculations being done on the XML. This then loads a new page in the same window with the resulting XML code. I am trying to parse through this and get a value out.

I am able to pull values for some of the tags, both a and span tags. The span tags return values close to what I need yet I have been unable to extract the exact value.

code:

```
'browser previously defined, it is on the page with the xml

Dim oHTML As HTMLDocument
Dim elements As IHTMLElementCollection

Set  oHTML = browser.document

Set elements = oHTML.getElementsByTagName("total_tax_amount")

Debug.Print elements.Length 

'above returns 0, there are about 20 of those elements in the document
```

expecting it to return 20-25 elements, however it returns 0.
The image shows what the html tags on the site look like in the first spot of total_tax_amount.

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

```
Set elements = oHTML.all

str = elements.Item(0).getElementsByTagName("TOTAL_TAX_AMOUNT")(i).textContent
```

Solved the problem, if anyone has this issue in the future.